# Why do I lose Razor code formatting after a </text> tag?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, devextreme

I have this bit of code from a .cshtml file in an ASP.NET Core application using DevExtreme controls:

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid()
    .ID("valueGrid")
    .DataSource(Model)
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add()
            .CellTemplate(
                    @<text>
                    @(Html.DevExtreme().CheckBox())
                    </text>
                )
                .Width("auto");
        columns.Add().DataField("Name");
        columns.Add().DataField("Age").Width("auto");
    })
)
```

Everything about it works and the page renders fine, but none of the code after the closing `</text>` tag has any IDE features. No syntax highlighting, no autocomplete, no auto-indentation, no grey background, etc. I've tried closing and reopening the file as well as the IDE itself, no change.

Comment: Anything inside the text tag is rendered as just that - text. I would guess..  Remove the text tags and have your parameter as just `Html.DevExtreme().CheckBox()`

Comment: Yes that's exactly what the text tag does, the problem is after the text tag is closed I lose all IDE features in the code following it, Checkbox() also returns a CheckBoxBuilder object which isn't a valid parameter for CellTemplate() hence the need for text blocks.